# Grunt.js Mocha task fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, mocha.js, mocha-phantomjs

When I run mocha task on grunt I get an error says "mocha was not initialized before the page finished loading. Make sure to include mocha.js as a direct script and call `mocha.ui` or `mocha.setup`."

```
// mocha command
    exec: {
        mocha: {
            command: 'mocha-phantomjs http://localhost:<%= connect.testserver.options.port %>/test',
            stdout: true
        }
    },
```

Can anybody help me with this error?